# how to intersect an interpolated surface z=f(x,y) with z=z0 in R

Tags: r, intersection, contour

I found some posts and discussions about the above, but I'm not sure... could someone please check if I am doing anything wrong?

I have a set of N points of the form (x,y,z). The x and y coordinates are independent variables that I choose, and z is the output of a rather complicated (and of course non-analytical) function that uses x and y as input.

My aim is to find a set of values of (x,y) where z=z0.

I looked up this kind of problem in R-related forums, and it appears that I need to interpolate the points first, perhaps using a package like `akima` or `fields`.

However, it is less clear to me: 1) if that is necessary, or the basic R functions that do the same are sufficiently good; 2) how I should use the interpolated surface to generate a correct matrix of the desired (x,y,z=z0) points.

E.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42983049/how-to-retrieve-isocontour-coordinates) seems somewhat related to the problem I am describing, but it looks extremely complicated to me, so I am wondering whether my simpler approach is correct.

Please see below some example code (not the original one, as I said the generating function for z is very complicated).

I would appreciate if you could please comment / let me know if this approach is correct / suggest a better one if applicable.

```
df <- merge(data.frame(x=seq(0,50,by=5)),data.frame(y=seq(0,12,by=1)),all=TRUE)
df["z"] <- (df$y)*(df$x)^2
ta <- xtabs(z~x+y,df)
contour(ta,nlevels=20)
contour(ta,levels=c(1000))
#why are the x and y axes [0,1] instead of showing the original values?
#and how accurate is the algorithm that draws the contour?
li2 <- as.data.frame(contourLines(ta,levels=c(1000)))
#this extracts the contour data, but all (x,y) values are wrong
require(akima)
s <- interp(df$x,df$y,df$z)
contour(s,levels=c(1000))
li <- as.data.frame(contourLines(s,levels=c(1000)))
#at least now the axis values are in the right range; but are they correct?
require(fields)
image.plot(s)
```

fancier, but same problem - are the values correct? better than the akima ones?

Comment: Please explain what the problem is. I see no errors in this code. (It appears you have not yet read the `?contour` help page.)

Comment: Hi @42- thank you for your comments. I will edit my question to make it clearer. BTW, yes, I did read the contour help page; trouble is I didn't understand it very well, hence my question.

Comment: The help page explains that the plot gets axes that are [0,1] so you need to give different labels.

Comment: This one seems to check out OK as far as accuracy and labeling: `s <- interp(df$x,df$y,df$z) ; contour(s,levels=c(1000))`. Check with `points(10,10)`

Comment: Thanks. In the meantime I found I probably can't use `akima`. So I'm stuck with `xtabs`. After further tests, it looks like `xtabs` keeps the values in my original data in the `dimnames` of `ta`. So to use them in contour I need something like: `contour(x=as.numeric(unlist(dimnames(ta)[1])),y=as.numeric(unlist(dimnames(ta)[2])),ta)`, and the same when extracting the values using `contourLines`. Hoping that the order is correct, because that's something I don't seem to have any control on, and numbers are turned into characters. And I hope `contourLines` with `xtabs` is accurate enough.